# How to sort when parsing XML to mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, xml-parsing

I'm beginner in JS. Example of XML file i cant upload.

I have a file that is parsed JS to mongo DB. How can I add a sorting there when prsing, which does not include null values ​​in  priceService:fullXML.Report.ds[i].i[j]['$'].f?

Part of code when i need sorting

```
   if(fullXML.Report.ds[i].i){
    for(var j=0;j<fullXML.Report.ds[i].i.length;j++){
      detallization.tel[i].callsAll[j]={
        date:fullXML.Report.ds[i].i[j]['$'].d,
        oneService:fullXML.Report.ds[i].i[j]['$'].n,
        priceService:fullXML.Report.ds[i].i[j]['$'].f,
        time:fullXML.Report.ds[i].i[j]['$'].du,
      }
    }
 }
```

I need something:

```
   if(fullXML.Report.ds[i].i){
    for(var j=0;j<fullXML.Report.ds[i].i.length;j++)
     if(fullXML.Report.ds[i].i[j]['$'].f>0){
       detallization.tel[i].callsAll[j]={            
         date:fullXML.Report.ds[i].i[j]['$'].d,
         oneService:fullXML.Report.ds[i].i[j]['$'].n,
         priceService:fullXML.Report.ds[i].i[j]['$'].f,
         time:fullXML.Report.ds[i].i[j]['$'].du,
```

But this solution does not work. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for my question

```
  

    if(fullXML.Report.ds[i].i){
            for(var j=0;j 0){
              detallization.tel[i].callsAll.push({
                date:fullXML.Report.ds[i].i[j]['$'].d,
                oneService:fullXML.Report.ds[i].i[j]['$'].n,
                priceService:fullXML.Report.ds[i].i[j]['$'].f,
                time:fullXML.Report.ds[i].i[j]['$'].du,
                })
              }
            }
         }
```